# Closed form expression for observation

Tags: combinatorics

Observation: Given a positive integer N, the total number p of unique combinations of integers $qi$, $(0 < qi < N)$ that sum to N is given by $p = SUM(qi) = 2^(N-1)$

eg $N = 4$ gives $p = 2^3 = 8$

$q1 = (1,1,1,1)$

$q2-q4 = (1, 3), (3,1), (2, 2)$

$q5-q7 = (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1)$

$q8 = (4)$

$Q1$ Is this correct and what is the proof of this observation ?

$Q2$ What is the general form for $p$ when $qi$ is restricted to $(0 < qi < n)$ where $n < N$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use Mathjax

Comment: Thanks Arman. This question is best posed as:

Comment: You're welcome :) see this page for Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

These are the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$.

Given a composition of $n$, you can create two of $n+1$, first
by adding $1$ to the last part, and second by adding an extra part $1$ at the end. The number of compositions doubles when going from $n$ to $n+1$.

Comment: Thanks Arman. This question is best posed as:
What are the compositions of N restricted to n  (n <N)
for which the answer appears to be ( 2^(N-1) - 2^(N-n) + 1)
PS still trying to figure out Mathjax